# Populating ListBox from C++ using Grid

Tags: c++, xaml, winapi, windows-embedded-compact

In specific, how do you take elements/models that are added to an [XRObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh336407.aspx) and use them to generate rows/columns in XAML listbox?

I have tried to do this on my own, but my listbox remains empty, despite having elements added to my collection.

**Note: This menu is being designed for a Windows Embedded Compact 7 device using VS2008 and Silverlight for Windows Embedded, so many features available in WPF do not apply to this environment.**

What i have done is initialize the model of the element i want to display in the listbox as follows:

```
DispCh->Initialize(ChannelNum,ChannelName,InputType,DispRange_Low,DispRange_High,MovingAvgFilter,EngUnit);
```

By substituting values in for those variables, you are defining what to display in each column of the listbox (implying that 1 row of the listbox will contain 6 columns; display range high and low are in 1 column).

Now i add this model of my element to the collection as follows:

`pMainPage->m_pDispChModelCollection->Add(DispCh);`

This works fine as when i check the collection count after adding, it increases.

Now, i believe that i have done the binding correctly to take the collection and convert it into the listbox. To do this, i do the following:

```
XRValue value;
value.vType = VTYPE_PROPERTYBAG;
value.pPropertyBagVal = m_pDispCh_Model;
m_pReviewModeDispCh->m_pReviewMode_ChList->SetDataContext(&value);
m_pDispCh_Model->Set_ChannelCollection(m_pDispChModelCollection);
```

where `m_pDispCh_Model` is the model class that contains all the xaml initialization and binding, `m_pReviewModeDispCh` is the class definition for the XAML menu, `m_pReviewMode_ChList` is the IXRPtr to the XAML listbox, and `Set_ChannelCollection` takes `m_pDispChModelCollection` and passes it to `m_pRevChList` which is the following:

```
TBoundPointerProperty<IXREnumerable> m_pRevChList;
hResult = RegisterBoundProperty(L"ReviewModeDispChList", m_pRevChList);
```

Now, i could post the code that shows what i did for the xaml menu, the c++ code for defining the xaml class, the c++ class for the element model, and the c++ code where i use these class methods, but it wouldnt follow the [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so instead, **i'd like to see if the idea behind steps i am doing are correct as far as the code i have provided** or at the very least if someone could point me in the right direction regarding generating listbox grids from C++ code.